# pushing arrays into an exisiting array using codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to push new data into an existing array `$query`:

```
$query = $this->db->get('questions');
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {

    $get_answers = $this->db->get_where('answers', array('question_id' => $row['question_id']), 4);
}
//push all the get_answers data into $query array as a subarray
return $query;
```

Comment: ...you mean `$query[] = $get_answers`?

Comment: yeh thats what i mean, but i still want the existing data to be thier from $query

Comment: Not from me, but I'm guessing someone didn't think this was well-researched or it was not useful. [Read this for tips on how to ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You'll get fewer down-votes and more up-votes by following the guidelines there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your $query variable there is actually an array, but rather a result set.  You ought to put that into an array as well.  Maybe something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('questions');
$result_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $result_array[$i] = $row;
    $result_array[$i]['answers'] = $this->db->get_where('answers', array('question_id'=>$row['question_id']), 4);
    $i++;
}

var_dump($result_array);
```

Comment: this is a very good example thanks you, when i return the result_array and json encode it, would it work?

Comment: It should assuming there is nothing int he content that is going to cause problems with the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Use `array_merge()` to merge both arrays.</s>

Simply add it to $query:

```
$query[] = $get_answers;
```

Comment: i don't wan to merge i want insert get_answers into an array as a subarray! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$query = $this->db->get('questions');
$answers = array();

foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $get_answers = $this->db->get_where('answers', array('question_id'=>$row['question_id']), 4);

    $answers[] = $get_answers;
}
```

Then you can just append `$answers[]` to `$query` (which, by the way, is a **terrible** name for a variable containing `result`s) by using `array_merge()`.

```
$returnArray = array_merge($answers, $query);

return $returnArray;
```